# Getting TypeError - can't clone Symbol: error when using active_model_serializer

Tags: ruby, json, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers

So I have Ruby 2.1.3 with Rails 4.2.0 and I am using the active_model_serializer gem to send proper json data to AngularJs.

Not I only upgraded today from Rails 4.1.6 to 4.2.0. With the previous version the problem did not exist.

The problem appears when I try to get json from my medium show action:

```
def show
        medium = Medium.find(params[:id])
        respond_with medium, include: [{comments: :user}, :likes, :user]
end
```

And this is how the same action looked before I upgraded rails:

```
def show
        medium = Medium.includes([{comments: :user}, :likes, :user]).find(params[:id])
        respond_with medium
end
```

It used to be able to work the old way but with the new rails, it does not have the included ActiveModels with the medium anymore in the sent json data.

So I changed the code using the examples on this page: https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers

Here is how my media serializer looks like:

```
class MediumSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id,
               :text,

               :image_video_file_name,
               :image_video_croppable_url,
               :image_video_thumb_url,
               :image_video_big_url

    has_one :user
    has_many :comments, :likes


end
```

Before the upgrade it looked like this:

```
class MediumSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id,
               :text,
               :image_video_file_name,
               :image_video_croppable_url,
               :image_video_thumb_url,
               :image_video_big_url

    has_one :user
    has_many :comments, :likes

    def include_user?
        object.association(:user).loaded?
    end

    def include_comments?
        object.association(:comments).loaded?
    end

    def include_associations?
        object.association(:user, :comments, :likes).loaded?
    end
end
```

So, when making a query for that show action, the error that my Rails application throws is this:

```
Started GET "/media/7.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-25 18:13:43 +0200
Processing by Content::MediaController#show as JSON
  Parameters: {"id"=>"7"}
  Medium Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "media".* FROM "media" WHERE "media"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 7]]
  Comment Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."medium_id" = $1  [["medium_id", 7]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 59ms

TypeError - can't clone Symbol:
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/core_ext/object/try.rb:77:in `try!'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/core_ext/object/try.rb:63:in `try'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/serialization.rb:12:in `serializable_hash'
  activemodel (4.2.0) lib/active_model/serialization.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in serializable_hash'
  activemodel (4.2.0) lib/active_model/serialization.rb:114:in `block in serializable_hash'
  activemodel (4.2.0) lib/active_model/serialization.rb:158:in `block in serializable_add_includes'
  activemodel (4.2.0) lib/active_model/serialization.rb:156:in `serializable_add_includes'
  activemodel (4.2.0) lib/active_model/serialization.rb:112:in `serializable_hash'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/serialization.rb:17:in `serializable_hash'
  activemodel (4.2.0) lib/active_model/serializers/json.rb:99:in `as_json'
  app/models/medium.rb:32:in `as_json'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:34:in `encode'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:21:in `encode'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/core_ext/object/json.rb:37:in `to_json_with_active_support_encoder'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:116:in `block in <module:Renderers>'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:45:in `block in _render_to_body_with_renderer'
  /home/kaspar/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/set.rb:263:in `each'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:41:in `_render_to_body_with_renderer'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:37:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
  /home/kaspar/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:294:in `realtime'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
  responders (2.0.2) lib/action_controller/responder.rb:258:in `display'
  responders (2.0.2) lib/action_controller/responder.rb:212:in `api_behavior'
  responders (2.0.2) lib/action_controller/responder.rb:191:in `rescue in to_format'
  responders (2.0.2) lib/action_controller/responder.rb:185:in `to_format'
  responders (2.0.2) lib/action_controller/responder.rb:163:in `respond'
  responders (2.0.2) lib/action_controller/responder.rb:156:in `call'
  responders (2.0.2) lib/action_controller/respond_with.rb:203:in `respond_with'
  app/controllers/content/media_controller.rb:17:in `show'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:42:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:802:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:647:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  better_errors (2.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (2.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (2.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  quiet_assets (1.1.0) lib/quiet_assets.rb:27:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
  passenger (4.0.56) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:74:in `process_request'
  passenger (4.0.56) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:141:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
  passenger (4.0.56) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:109:in `main_loop'
  passenger (4.0.56) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:455:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
```

Worth noting maybe that if I remove both of the :user includes from the new `include:` method, then everything works. But I want each comment to also include the user that created it and medium to also include the user that uploaded it.

What could be the problem here? Let me know if some more info is needed.

EDIT: The problem seems to be only with the `:user` for `comments:`.

Posting my comments serializer here:

```
class CommentSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id,
               :text,
               :user_id,
               :medium_id

    has_one :user
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I encountered the same error using the built in ActiveModel serializer for JSON. You can overwrite a model's [`as_json` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json) with similar syntax to your `respond_with` call. Using your models I had

```
include: [{comments: :user} ... ]
```

when what I needed was

```
include: [{comments: {include: [:user]}}, ... ]
```

See if the following change fixes your problem (if you're still having it).

Change

```
respond_with medium, include: [{comments: :user}, :likes, :user]
```

to

```
respond_with medium, include: [{comments: {include: [:user]}}, :likes, :user]
```